# Building RESTFul Web Services using Jackson Exception

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson

I have issues developing a simple REST endpoint. I'm using Glassfish 4.1.1 as a Server. When i deploy the app and run localhost:8080/HelloRest/students/1 , I get this exception

> ```
> Warning: StandardWrapperValve[org.stefan.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet org.stefan.ApplicationConfig threw exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper
> ```

These are my configurations:

```
package org.stefan;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;


@ApplicationPath("rest/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        packages("org.stefan","com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json");

    }
}
```

This is my resource class:

```
package org.stefan;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/students")
public class StudentResource {

    StudentDAO dao=new StudentDAO();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Student> findAll() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    @GET @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Student findById(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return dao.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));
    }

}
```

And these are the two dependencies i use:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I did a lot of research on the internet and didn't come up with a solution. I'm sure there is something that has to be added to my configurations or is wrong. But this is just not working at the moment, so decided to pop up with a question. Also, my Student class has an empty constructor with no parameters as well.

Comment: Try and put `<scope>provided</scope>` for the `jersey-server` dependency

Comment: Jaxb not found, your program lack the libraries to run, so check glassfish server already have that libs(in ext folder), if not have, put <provided> to maven dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your problem, but if you need a quick workaround you could import Jackson lib to your project and do the serialization/deserialization manually.

For example, you could check [this](https://github.com/asterics/AsTeRICS/blob/master/ARE/services/WebService/src/main/java/eu/asterics/mw/webservice/serverUtils/ObjectTransformation.java) class which uses jackson (not the latest version though) and provides the functionality that you need. You just have to convert the object you want to sent as a response with this code:

```
String jsonString = ObjectTransformation.objectToJSON(object);
```

In your case i suppose this code will go somewhere inside the DAO object. You should only keep in mind that usually every object should contain some annotations as specified in Jackson documentation.

Hope this helps.